# ¿Por qué _=$=+[],++_+''+$ es igual a 10?

Tags: javascript

Leyendo me encontré esta expresión:

```
_=$=+[],++_+''+$
```

curiosamente es una expresión válida en `javascript` pero lo más curioso es que al ejecutarla, el resultado es:

```
10
```

Traté de encontrarle sentido descomponiendo la expresión pero no logré mucho.

¿Por qué el resultado de dicha expresión es igual a `10`?

Comment: jaja espero ayude var1=var2=+[],++var1+''               +var1+''+5*var1+''+3*var1

Comment: por cierto cuantos puntos tienes ? Saludos

Comment: Porque JavaScript es una locura. Ejecuta esto: `[] + []`, luego `{} + {}`, luego `[] - []` y por último `{} - {}`. El último de esos 4 lo puedes cambiar por `Array(16).join({} - {}) + " Batman"` para que entiendas por qué JS es una locura total.

Comment: Por cierto esta expresión solo funciona cuando no se activa modo estricto. Intenta usando `node --use_strict` y luego escribiendo `_=$=+[],++_+''+$` te dará `Reference Error: $ is not defined`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Aqui está la respuesta a lo que pones http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the ;)

Comment: @devconcept no lo ponía como pregunta. Sí sé lo que sucede.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Je, lo sé. Lo escribí para que conste que hasta los comportamientos más raros son "normales" o_0 y están documentados.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Fácil, esta expresión

```
_=$=+[],++_+''+$
```

Puede ser escrita de forma más legible así

```
_ = $ = +[], ++_ + '' + $
```

Que puede ser entendida como:

```
(_ = $ = +[]), (++_ + '' + $)
```

Que es lo mismo que:

```
_ = $ = +[];
++_ + '' + $;
```

Que es lo mismo que:

```
$ = +[];
_ = $;
++_ + '' + $;
```

Que para leerlo más fácil podremos renombrar variables como:

```
var1 = +[];                 // +[] fuerza al empty array a volverse number 0
var2 = var1;                // Ahora var1 y var2 valen 0
++var2 + '' + var1;         // ++var2 === 1, 1 + '' === '1' y '1' + 0 === '10'
```

Que ejecutándolo paso por paso:

```
var1 = 0;
var2 = var1;              
++var2 + '' + var1  
...
var2 = 0;              
++var2 + '' + var1;
...
++var2 + '' + 0;       //var2 === 0
...
1 + '' + 0;
...
'1' + 0;
...
'10';
```

Answer (score 5):

Hagamos algunas transformaciones. A lo que llama `_` voy a llamarlo `a` y a lo que llama `$` voy a llamarlo `b`. Simplemente cambié el nombre de estas dos variables, por lo que su expresión original ahora es:

```
a=b=+[],++a+''+b
```

Bajo esta expresión equivalente:

```
a =  
   b = + [] 
           , 
             ++a+''+b
```

1. El operador con mayor precedencia es el operador `,` (coma). Este operador evalúa cada uno de sus operandos de izquierda a derecha y retorna el valor de la última expresión que evaluó.
2. Evalúa la expresión `a = b = +[]`. Esta expresión es una expresión de asignación compuesta. El operador de asignación `=` asocia de derecha a izquierda, por lo tanto, esta expresión debe evaluarse como `a = (b = +[])`
3. La expresión `b = +[]` le asigna a una variable `b` (que debe resolverla primera dentro de la cadena del scope: si existe, le asigna el valor adecuado, si no existe -como en este ejemplo- crea una propiedad llamada `b` en el objeto global (en el navegador sería el objeto `window`). A esa variable le asigna el valor `+[]`. El operador unitario `+` se encarga de convertir un tipo de dato a un valor entero. En este caso, se intenta convertir el arreglo vacío `[]`. Cuando en un arreglo se usa el operador `+`, Javascript llama al método `toString()` del arreglo, devolviendo una representación en cadena de caracteres del contenido del mismo. Como el arreglo está vacío, devuelve la cadena `''`. Ahora, el estándar [ECMA](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) menciona que la representación de una cadena de texto vacía al convertirla en un número es el valor entero 0, por lo tanto, la expresión `b = +[]` le asigna a `b` el valor 0.
4. Este valor 0 es asignado a la variable `a`, la cual, al igual que la variable `b`, si existe, se le asigna el valor, si no, se crea como propiedad en el objeto global. Hasta aquí, lo que se hizo fue crear dos variables llamadas a y b que tienen asignado el valor 0 y que existen en el objeto global.
5. A continuación se evalúa el segundo operando de la expresión `,`: `++a+''+b`. Debido a la aparición de la cadena de carácteres vacía `''`. los operadores `+` que aparecen actuarán concatenando cadenas de carácteres. Este operador evalúa de izquierda a derecha.
6. En primer lugar, evalúa la expresión `++a`. Esta expresión contiene el operador de incremento unitario prefijo `++`: su labor es aumentar en 1 el valor de la variable y devolver ese resultado. Por lo tanto, `a`, que es 0, ahora es 1 y retorna este valor.
7. El operador `+` concatena el valor obtenido por el operando izquierdo (que devolvió el valor entero 1) con la cadena de carácteres vacía `''`. Esta labor promueve el valor entero 0 a la cadena de caracteres '1'. Finalmente retorna este resultado.
8. El operador `+` concatena el valor obtenido por el operando izquierdo (que devolvió la cadena de caracteres '1' con el operando derecho. El operando derecho es simplemente el valor de la variable `b`, que es 0. Nuevamente, el operador `+` promociona este valor entero a la cadena de caracteres '0', debido a la concatenación. La concatenación del operando izquierdo con el derecho es '1'+ '0' = '10' y devuelve este resultado.
9. Finalmente, como al comienzo mencioné, el operador `,` devuelve el resultado que la última expresión devolvió, en este caso, devolverá la cadena de caracteres '10', que es el resultado que usted obtiene.